# Phaser game destroy() not working

Tags: javascript, meteor, phaser-framework

I am currently using Phaser with Meteor and I want to destroy the game when I switch to another page. And create the game again when I go back.

But when I check Phaser.GAMES I see something like this:
[Phaser.Game, Phaser.Game, Phaser.Game, Phaser.Game, Phaser.Game]

And then, the canvas gets black. I've tried setting the game variable to null, tried set to null the items inside the Phaser.GAMES but had no success.

The strange thing is, when I check the source code, it shows  *Phaser.GAMES[this.id] = null* but it keeps the value.I checked the source code (https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/master/src/core/Game.js) and I added the extra logic to *destroy()* missing from the version I am currently using (2.1.3) but it was not working either.

I tried to just hide it, but in slower machines, it just slows down the entire site keeping the game running.

I am using Phaser v2.1.3 | Pixi.js v2.0.0. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It was the version. I was using Phaser 2.1.3, the first version with Pixi 2.0.0. I downgraded to the version 2.1.2 and it was ok.

> meteor add robertlowe:meteor-phaser@=2.1.2

This should be fixed with Pixi v3 (not out yet). I got the info from here: https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/issues/1238

A good way to find problems in Phaser is to switch the canvas to Phaser.CANVAS, or to look for the issue in Pixi.

Comment: I missed something. When I do it around 12 times, instead of going black, it zooms a lot for some reason. Still not solved